# Problem with Spring and database connection

Tags: java, html, spring

I got a problem with my connection via database and spring. I searching in all ends of internet for resolution but without success

My problem is about retrieve my list of class from database to Spring. I want to do an electronic journey app, and this is only one thing I cannot pass. So my question is -> what i need to get that connection? ( maybe some `ClassDAO`, `ClassRepository`, more)

So, my Class.java looks like this

```
package com.example.JournalElectronic.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Class {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String classNr;
    private int roomNr;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getClassNr() {
        return classNr;
    }

    public void setClassNr(String classNr) {
        this.classNr = classNr;
    }

    public int getRoomNr() {
        return roomNr;
    }

    public void setRoomNr(int roomNr) {
        this.roomNr = roomNr;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

}
```

and my "some" html file ->

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button> class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Klasy
</button>
<tr th:each var="emp" items="${classList}" varStatus="status">
    <tr>
        <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
        <td>${emp.name}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

And my second is about separate css out of .html file. My friend added all css actions into .html files, and I want to separate (for good looking code), but if i do with "ref" I cannot see colours and all of my buttons all messed up.

Comment: You forgot to ask an actual question. Since your wording sounds like you intended to ask two questions, please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: More context would be helpful in figuring out the problem here. For example, I don't see any connection to the Spring application from your HTML file, so I don't know where the problem might be occurring.

Comment: I don't know how to retrieve a records from database, for example can You told me what to do from the start ? Maybe there i can get some solution

Comment: This is what tutorials are for (e.g. [this official Spring Getting Started guide for MySQL databases](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/)).

Comment: Thx a lot ;) I was looking for it but maybe the best solution is a start from the beginning ^.^'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the css code in a seperate .css file and link it to the HTML like so `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/css/some.css"/>"/>`?

Comment: Yes, but this is not work, becouse my site view was messed up, i mean colours and buttons was in other places than before ;//

Comment: Maybe you just have to create unique names for the css classes in this HTML file? Sounds like the colours and buttons are being overwritten somewhere else because of class names.

Comment: Problem is that i was named in likes in the tutorial, i can show You screens to show You what i mean and how it works